# .htaccess Rewrite to this Pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URLs which is in the format

```
http://mysite.com/display.php?name=sequin-cuff-swing-dress&id=---DT0001
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/sequin-cuff-swing-dress---DT0001
```

Please can anyone help me with this.

**NB:** I already have a Rule as below existing for a different URL rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /products.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule **on top of other rule:**:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)(---[^/]+)/?$ /display.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]

# your existing rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /products.php?cat=$1 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance here again. I'm pleased. With your solution here, the Rule for products.php works fine but the display.php returns a 404 error page. Any suggestions? My browser can't find the page http://mysite.com/sequin-cuff-swing-dress---DT0001

Comment: `/sequin-cuff-swing-dress---DT0001` will internally become: `/display.php?name=sequin-cuff-swing-dress&id=DT001` now try: `http?/site.com/display.php?name=sequin-cuff-swing-dress&id=DT001` to see if can even get this working. Most likely `display.php` is not in root may be?

Comment: `http://site.com/display.php?name=sequin-cuff-swing-dress&id=DT001` directly on the browser works fine. The rewrite doesn't. It returns 404 Error page. Thanks for you keen assistance.

Comment: I suspect some other code conflicting. Can you make first rule `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)(---[a-z0-9]+)/?$ /display.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R]` and see what URL do you get in browser?

Comment: Thanks pal. You're a saviour. I figured out that once there's a space in the id="" it will return 404 but without a space or any character, it works fine. Thanks for the lead. If you can offer a solution for the space or special characters like "_,-" within the id="" I'll be pleased.

Comment: Sure I can try that. Can you give a sample of URL with space/special characters?

Comment: Two samples are: `http://site.com/display.php?name=sequin-cuff-swing-dress&id=DT_0001` (This has an underscore "DT_001") or `http://site.com/display.php?name=sequin-cuff-swing-dress&id=DT 001` (This has a space "DT 001")

Comment: ok check the edited code, It should work with those special cases.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava!!!!!!! You've made my day easier after some tough hours of research.